Why does dimV = dim nullT + dim rangeT?
I am reading this textbook titled "Linear Algebra Done Right" by Sheldon Axler, the fourth edition, but the fundamental theorem of linear maps doesn't quite make sense to me. it says that $$dimV = dim\ nullT +dim\ rangeT$$, but what doesn't make sense to me is that, couldn't both $dim\ nullT$ & $dim\ rangeT$ share the zero vector, causing the length of $dimV$ to be $1$ larger than it should be? I've been trying to look around in the textbook and it says that $nullT$ is the list of vectors that T maps to $0$, and $rangeT$ is the list of vectors that T maps to some vector such that $v\in V$. Wouldn't "some vector" include the zero vector?
I am also quite new to this forum so if possible, try to explain in simple terms or elaborate on what some symbols or terms mean, thanks.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank%E2%80%93nullity_theorem

What you wrote makes no sense. You wrote that $\dim\operatorname{null}T$ and $\dim\operatorname{range}T$ could share the zero vector. Really?  $\dim\operatorname{null}T$ and $\dim\operatorname{range}T$ are just non-negative integers. If, say,  $\dim\operatorname{null}T=2$ and $\dim\operatorname{range}T=5$, what does it mean that $2$ and $5$ share the zero vector?

Ah, sorry, by that I was trying to say that dim V would be one more than it should be if nullT and rangeT subspaces contained the zero vector as part of their basis, which would then contribute to the length of their basis, but I'm likely lacking some understanding of this part. Upon further research I found that a basis can't include the zero vector, so that piece of information I believe fixed the misunderstanding. My apologies for asking a dumb question, I am trying to learn solely from this textbook out of personal interest, which I'm unsure of as a good learning method. @JoséCarlosSantos
